# Does using a modulus with rand() limit results?

Tags: c++, random, modulus

This is a program created for a game, in which I am using `rand()` to try and generate randomly what types of trees can be found at a settlement. The seed for `rand()` has been set to time in main.cpp so that it is unique each time. My question here however is about my modulus: `trees[x]=rand()%40;`

If I understand how `rand()` works correctly, once it outputs a number it has already outputted, it will repeat the same number sequence it has already because it uses a formula. Is using the modulus limiting my program to only produce 40 different random number sequences? Or does it continue to draw the new random number for each of the following arrays from the system clock?

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()
#include <ctime> // for time()
using namespace std;

int forestdeterminator()
{
int trees[32];
for (int x=0; x<32; ++x)
    trees[x]=rand()%40;

    if (trees[0]>=1 && trees[0]<=9)
        cout << "Birch Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[1]>=1 && trees[1]<=3)
        cout << "Mahogany Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[2]>=1 && trees[2]<=20)
        cout << "Oak Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[3]>=1 && trees[3]<=4)
        cout << "Cherry Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[4]==1)
        cout << "Tigerwood Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[5]==1)
        cout << "Swampwood Trees (Swamp Only)" << endl;
    if (trees[6]>=1 && trees[6]<=8)
        cout << "Yew Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[7]==1)
        cout << "Petrified Trees" << endl;
    if (trees[8]>=1 && trees[8]<=24)
        cout << "Pine Trees" << endl;
    if etc etc...
```

Comment: `rand()` is usually not a very good PRNG, and modulus arithmetic for range limiting makes it worse. You should really use the C++11 or Boost random number facilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are only using the **result** of the `rand()` function, so it has absolutely no effect on the output of the PRNG. Only if you used `rand()%40` to  successively seed the PRNG would you run into that limit.

Also, note that a PRNG is typically only seeded from the system clock once, at its initialization. From there on, each number "depends" on the previously outputted one.

Finally, be aware that using a modulus on the output of a PRNG will in almost all cases skew the resulting probability distribution. This effect is very **very** small, for small modulus, but may be important to consider, depending on your application.

Comment: @jacisback If you consider your question to be answered, please tick the checkmark next to the answer you want to accept

Comment: @goncalopp: I think you might have meant "skew" not "eschew"?

Answer (score 0):

> Is using the modulus limiting my program to only produce 40 different random number sequences?

Sequences, debatable. *Numbers*. Definitely. You can't have effective randomness with only `40` possible outputs; there's just not enough freedom there to fluctuate. But no, you're not effecting the numbers that are outputted, you're just heavily limiting what the output of *your program* is.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is put 32 (pseudo)randomly generated integers in range from 0 to 39 to an array called trees. doing this doesn't affect how the function rand() works. it'll keep generating numbers from the full scope, no matter what operations you apply to it's former results.

so, if I understand you, the answer is: no, using rand()%40 somewhere in your code won't magically make the rand() function generate only numbers from range 0-39.